# How to monitor outgoing messages from TIBCO EMS .Net client?

Tags: .net, jms, tibco, tibco-ems

While using the .Net client TIBCO EMS, How to monitor outgoing messages from my .Net Tibco client?

I'm going to send Application-level, not jms-level, acknowlegements and replies. 
How can I tell If the application sent them or not? If the client failed to send a message will it throw an exception or store the message to try again later?

Bottom line, Is there any tool enables me to monitor activities(outgoing) from client point of view?

Comment: try sniffing your tcp outgoing messages, If you use application level acknowlegements

Comment: I'll give it a try when I have time, but I have doubt It'll work. What if we shift to SSL communication on production which is reasonable & expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While using the .Net client TIBCO EMS,
>   How to monitor outgoing messages from
>   my .Net Tibco client?

What is it exactly that you want to monitor, is it the actual messages on the bus/EMS or the workings of your client (not including the client libraries)? The first I'll answer below, the second you can handle with regular logging. I suggest log4Net or similar library for that.

> I'm going to send Application-level,
>   not jms-level, acknowlegements and
>   replies. How can I tell If the
>   application sent them or not?

I suggest you log this internally just above the client dll level (see next question).

> If the client failed to send a message
>   will it throw an exception or store
>   the message to try again later?

Depending on the specific problem the EMS client dlls will either throw an exception or in the case of a lost connection, attempt to reconnect. In the second case the number of attempts depends on how the connection factory is configured (ask your EMS administrator).

The exceptions thrown by the client depend on the problem, they all inherit from TIBCO.EMS.EMSException and they are all listed in your API documentation(!).

> Bottom line, Is there any tool enables
>   me to monitor activities(outgoing)
>   from client point of view?

There are several tools that will allow you to monitor the EMS and specific destinations. When monitoring destinations they will most likely use the monitoring topics mentioned by both Anders and c. liau. (a practical example is "$sys.monitor.Q.*.queue.sample"). Subscribing to a monitor topic is like subscribing to any other topic and is possible with the client libraries, you do not need a specific tool for this. You do however need elevated user rights.

It sounds to me like you have not gotten sufficient documentation with your client libraries. Personally I do not see the need for monitoring your destinations from your application, in fact I would strongly question that design. Correct exception handling and internal logging should be sufficient to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks stoft, I think I did part of your solution, internal logging using log4net. Moreover, I understood what other answers meant. They weren't clear enough until I read your response.

Answer (score 2):

The TIBCO ems server comes with a tool called tibemsmonitor which is useful if you have traffic going out on topics.

tibemsmonitor -monitor 
[-server ]
[-user ]
[-password ]
[-selector ]
[-short]
[-help]
[-helpssl]

Linky: http://tibcoadmin.com/quick-reference/

If you monitor $sys.monitor.> you can get quite a lot of administrative messages, e.g. send/acknowledges etc.

Comment: I mentioned that I'm just a client & I have the .net client dlls only.

Answer (score 1):

tibemsmonitor
TIBCO HAWK
Or use an intermediate custom proxy client..
Or at core as network traffic sniffer.. www.sysinternals.com

Comment: Thanks hB0, but I don't have EMS as I said before, I just have a .net client only. AFAIK now, there's no such a free too enables me to do this. I have to purchase TIBCO EMS tools in order to accomplish this.

Comment: I didn't realized you specified no EMS.. well EMS is basically a JMS implementation, so perhaps check for JMS monitors on the web and try plugging it with TIBCO EMS.

Answer (score 1):

Try $sys.monitor.> with this tool

https://anderstool.dev.java.net

Comment: the problem I only have the TIBCO.EMS.dll & TIBCO.EMS.Admin.dll & this tool requires tibemsadmin.exe. How can I get it? From where can I download TIBCO EMS client libraries (for Java or .Net)?

Comment: I have tried to install anderstool v0.8 but it doesn't work! does it work for you ?

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gems utility tool for monitoring tibco EMS
https://community.tibco.com/wiki/graphical-administration-tool-tibcor-ems-gems

It's pretty good tool for setup and monitoring EMS server. Today's latest version is 5.1
Gems provides the following main features:

> - Server Monitoring. Server state and main statistics are automticaly    updated, warning and error limits may be configured. Server generated 
>     events are also captured.
> - Server Management. Including, general server configuration, JMS destinations, JNDI factories, users/groups, permissions, bridges,
>     routes etc.
> - JMS support. Messages may be sent/received, queues may be browsed and message contents inspected. Selectors and filters may be
>     specified.
> - JMS Message Monitoring. Messages may be monitored (snooped) as they pass through the server. Request and reply messages can be
>     correlated to provide service response times.
> - JMS Message Management. Eg; purging messages, copy messages from a queue to another queue on a different server.
> - Charting. Server statistics may be charted in real time, data may be saved to CSV files for export to other tools such as Excel.
> - Logging. Server statistics may be logged automatically when warning or error limits are breached.
> - Security. SSL connectivity, view only mode.
> - Customisable display and look and feel.
> - Support for Managing and Monitoring TIBCO SubStation.
> - Support for Monitoring TIBCO EMS Appliance.
> - Support for Migrating to TIBCO EMS Appliance