# How to connect TIBO EMS using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, tibco, tibco-ems

We have a requirement in our project to read the messages from TIBCO EMS using SSIS. As I know there no out of box feature to connect EMS using SSIS. Could anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: It is recommended to read the [tour page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about accepting, up-voting another rules since you asked two questions and it looks like you ignored answers provided. If they solved the issue why not accepting them else write a feedback (comment) to get more help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search for TIBCO ODBC adapter and use ODBC connection manager from SSIS:

- [Tibco Database Adapter: Step By Step Tutorial](http://tutorialspedia.com/tibco-database-adapter-step-by-step-tutorial/)
- [TIBCO Spotfire® Database Drivers](https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-database-drivers)

**Update**

There is no component to read data from TIBCO EMS, in order to achieve that you have to consume data from EMS using TIBCO EMS .net API and a Script Component as a source, since i didn't works before with TIBCO services i will try to provide some helpful links on how to use Script component as source and how to use .net api:

*TIBCO EMS .Net API*

- [SSIS to Tibco EMS messaging](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/85b2bfc6-8bcb-4404-bd37-f74db92cde41/ssis-to-tibco-ems-messaging?forum=sqlintegrationservices)
- [Connecting to Tibco EMS from a C# Client](https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/connecting-to-tibco-ems-from-a-c-client/)
- [Not able to retrieve messages from topic using EMS.NET API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444577/not-able-to-retrieve-messages-from-topic-using-ems-net-api)
- [All I have is a Tibco.EMS.dll, what else do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803536/all-i-have-is-a-tibco-ems-dll-what-else-do-i-need)
- [How to monitor outgoing messages from TIBCO EMS .Net client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176213/how-to-monitor-outgoing-messages-from-tibco-ems-net-client)

*Using Script Component as Source*

- [Creating a Source with the Script Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-data-flow-script-component-types/creating-a-source-with-the-script-component?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS Script Component as Source](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/ssis-script-component-as-source/)
- [SSIS – USING A SCRIPT COMPONENT AS A SOURCE](http://www.ssistalk.com/2007/04/04/ssis-using-a-script-component-as-a-source/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, however, I am not looking database adapter. I need to subscribe to the TIBO EMS and read the messages using SSIS.